# populate() Not Returning all Related Model Fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting some troubles populating an array that contains a ref to an model that I have.

This is my Player model:

```
const PlayerSchema = new Schema({
    gamer: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Gamer'
    },
    kills: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    deaths: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    isAlive: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }   
});
```

And this is my Match model:

```
const MatchSchema = new Schema({
    room: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Room'
    },
    team_one: [ {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Player'} ],
    team_two: [ {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Player'} ],
    finished: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});
```

Basically two teams of players.. so when I'm doing some updates for kills or deaths, I need to populate these values to send to my view.. I'm populating like this way (according to the docs):

```
var match = await Match.findOne({ room: room_id }).populate( { path: 'team_one' } )
```

So I got this population:

```
 { team_one: 
   [ { isAlive: true, _id: 5bf8c75ae2b9040f6298d46f },
     { isAlive: true, _id: 5bf8c75ae2b9040f6298d470 } ],
  team_two: [],
  finished: false,
  _id: 5bf8c75ae2b9040f6298d473,
  room: 5bf4e29460e3af20eb842a3b,
  __v: 0 }
```

As can you see this just populates two fields of my Player model(isAlive, _id), I need all fields to send to my view.. What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
My application already saved two teams with two players each one, at this point I think that I just need to populate that data and send to my view, but I not sure what's wrong.

```
> db.players.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bf8c75ae2b9040f6298d46f"), "isAlive" : true, "gamer" : ObjectId("5bf236cf36b3ee339d268eab"), "kills" : 202, "deaths" : 33, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bf8c75ae2b9040f6298d470"), "isAlive" : true, "gamer" : ObjectId("5bf4dffda9299a1e88fdbacd"), "kills" : 46, "deaths" : 31, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bf8c75ae2b9040f6298d472"), "isAlive" : true, "gamer" : ObjectId("5bf4e006a9299a1e88fdbacf"), "kills" : 34, "deaths" : 202, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bf8c75ae2b9040f6298d471"), "isAlive" : true, "gamer" : ObjectId("5bf4e003a9299a1e88fdbace"), "kills" : 76, "deaths" : 11, "__v" : 0 }

> db.matches.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bf8c75ae2b9040f6298d473"),   
  "finished" : false, 
  "room" : ObjectId("5bf4e29460e3af20eb842a3b"), 
  "team_one" : [ 
               { "_id" : ObjectId("5bf8c75ae2b9040f6298d46f") }, 
               { "_id" : ObjectId("5bf8c75ae2b9040f6298d470") } 
  ], 
  "team_two" : [ 
               { "_id" : ObjectId("5bf8c75ae2b9040f6298d471") }, 
               { "_id" : ObjectId("5bf8c75ae2b9040f6298d472") } 
  ], "__v" : 0 }
```

Comment: Considering that `isAlive` is the only other value in the schema with a set `"default"` then it would appear that your attempts to save the data in the first place is where the actual problem is. Not a problem with `populate()`, but in how the actual data has been stored. Or rather "not stored". You probably used key names which were not valid for the schema.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, in fact they are data that exists on my player and match documents anyway I'm not sure if I'm populating correctly

Comment: Show us these documents then within your question. Chances are the documents you think should be showing are actually not the correct ones associated with this document. Repeating myself but, this is NOT a populate problem. Your data is the problem.

Comment: Ok I have that documents on my DB (edited)

Comment: Your data does not match the schema. Those arrays in the `matches` document should be like `"team_one" : [ ObjectId("5bf8c75ae2b9040f6298d46f"), ObjectId("5bf8c75ae2b9040f6298d470")]` with no Object and `_id` property. Either you should fix the data or change the schema to match this. ie `"team_one": [{ "_id": { "type": ObjectId, ref: "Player" } }]`. If you opt to change the schema, then you do `populate("team_one._id")` instead. But I would probably fix the data by preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema and data are mismatched. The big issue here is the stored items are like:

```
"team_one" : [ 
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5bf8c75ae2b9040f6298d46f") }, 
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5bf8c75ae2b9040f6298d470") } 
  ],
```

But your mongoose schema says:

```
team_one: [ {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Player'} ],
```

So you need to change things either in the data or in the schema itself, so let's run through the options:

### Option 1 - Fix the Schema

To match the current stored state of the data, the schema should instead be:

```
const matchSchema = new Schema({
  room: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Room' },
  team_one: [{
    _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player' }
  }],
  team_two: [{
    _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player' }
  }],
  finished: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
```

This means that any code using the schema in that form should be aware of the `_id` value present for each array member just as you have them stored. There is this sort of change in adding a new match with players attached:

```
let match = await Match.create({
  room,
  team_one: [{ _id: player1 }, { _id: player2 }],
  team_two: [{ _id: player3 }, { _id: player4 }],
});
```

And `populate()` would also reference each path with the `_id` included:

```
// View populated
let populated = await Match.findOne({ room: room._id })
  .populate('team_one._id')
  .populate('team_two._id');
```

### Option 2 - Change the Data

Your current schema is defined in a way which is not expecting Objects with an `_id` property within them. The expected storage for that format looks more like:

```
{
  "team_one": [
    ObjectId("5bfa37f9a4da3c65bd984257"),
    ObjectId("5bfa37f9a4da3c65bd984258")
  ],
  "team_two": [
    ObjectId("5bfa37f9a4da3c65bd984259"),
    ObjectId("5bfa37f9a4da3c65bd98425a")
  ],
  "finished": false,
  "_id": ObjectId("5bfa37f9a4da3c65bd98425b"),
  "room": ObjectId("5bfa37f9a4da3c65bd984252"),
  "__v": 0
}
```

This is pretty much the legacy form of referenced data with Mongoose and what you basically have defined, but it's just your current data does not match. You can then convert the data and then working with corrected data follows the expected form.

Both for insertion:

```
let match = await Match.create({
  room,
  team_one: [player1, player2],
  team_two: [player3, player4],
});
```

And for `populate()`:

```
let populated = await Match.findOne({ room: room._id })
  .populate('team_one')
  .populate('team_two');
```

### Option 3 - Embed the data

The modelling in use is actually very relational, which is not possibly not really the best choice here.

In the cases where your access pattern typically does mean that you work with the "players within the match" most of the time, then it usually makes a lot more sense to embed the data.

This would change schema definition like:

```
const playerSchema = new Schema({
  gamer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Gamer' },
  kills: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  deaths: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  isAlive: { type: Boolean, default: true }
});

const matchSchema = new Schema({
  room: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Room' },
  players: [{
    team: { type: Number, required: true },
    player: playerSchema
  }],
  finished: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
```

And instead of defining a `'Player'` model, then the only actual storage is embedded within the `'Match'` model which gives a creation pattern like:

```
let match = await Match.create({
  room,
  players: [
    { team: 1, player: player1 },
    { team: 1, player: player2 },
    { team: 2, player: player3 },
    { team: 2, player: player4 }
  ]
});
```

Note also the change to `players` as a *single* array there. MongoDB really is not happy with being optimal with indexes where multiple arrays within documents are involved. There are other reasons within query and update, as well as aggregation of information which also lean towards the *single* array as being a far better idea.

The access for this then becomes very simple since there is nothing to `populate()` as the data is already in the match document.

```
let storedMatch = await Match.findOne({ _id: match._id });
```

And in storage it thus looks just like you would expect from a populated result.

### Option 4 - Virtual References

In cases where either the data to be stored within embedded arrays would be too large to keep within or where the access pattern really favors *mostly* working with just the players associated with a match, ( and more generally in operation solely on that one player at at time ) then it usually makes the most sense to have nothing recorded on the `match` at all, and instead move the reference to the `match` onto the `player`:

```
const playerSchema = new Schema({
  match: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Match' },
  team: { type: Number },
  gamer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Gamer' },
  kills: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  deaths: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  isAlive: { type: Boolean, default: true }
});

const matchSchema = new Schema({
  room: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Room' },
  finished: { type: Boolean, default: false }
},{
  toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});

matchSchema.virtual('players', {
  ref: 'Player',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'match'
});
```

The same thing applies there to the `team` by recording that there as well and this is basically for the same reasons as with the embedded solution with the exception that you are storing in a different collection.

Creation then actually works the other way around, and probably more logically since you would create the `match` before creating players associated with that `match`:

```
// Create match first
let match = await Match.create({ room });

// Add players with match reference
let [player1, player2, player3, player4] = await Player.insertMany(
  gamers.map(({ _id: gamer }, i) =>
    ({ match, team: (i <= 1) ? 1 : 2, gamer })
  )
);
```

Retrieving populated results actually works because of the set up which was added to the end of the schema, where we specified a `virtual` field which can be referenced:

```
let populated = await Match.findOne({ room: room._id })
  .populate('players')
```

And that returns the data just like all the others

---

### Listings

Example listings demonstrating each form in action:

**Option 1**

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/matches';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

// sensible defaults
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

// schema defs

const roomSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

const gamerSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
})

const playerSchema = new Schema({
  gamer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Gamer' },
  kills: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  deaths: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  isAlive: { type: Boolean, default: true }
});

const matchSchema = new Schema({
  room: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Room' },
  team_one: [{
    _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player' }
  }],
  team_two: [{
    _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player' }
  }],
  finished: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

const Room = mongoose.model('Room', roomSchema);
const Gamer = mongoose.model('Gamer', gamerSchema);
const Player = mongoose.model('Player', playerSchema);
const Match = mongoose.model('Match', matchSchema);

// log helper
const log  = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

// main
(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    // clean models
    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k, m]) => m.deleteMany())
    )

    // Insert to set up

    let room = await Room.create({ name: 'Room1' });

    let gamers = await Gamer.insertMany(
      [ ...Array(4)].map((e,i) => ({ name: 'Gamer' + (i+1) }))
    );

    let [player1, player2, player3, player4] = await Player.insertMany(
      gamers.map(({ _id: gamer }) => ({ gamer }))
    );

    let match = await Match.create({
      room,
      team_one: [{ _id: player1 }, { _id: player2 }],
      team_two: [{ _id: player3 }, { _id: player4 }],
    });

    // View match
    let storedMatch = await Match.findOne({ _id: match._id });
    log(storedMatch);

    // View populated
    let populated = await Match.findOne({ room: room._id })
      .populate('team_one._id')
      .populate('team_two._id');

    log(populated);


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect()
  }

})()
```

**Option 2**

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/matches';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

// sensible defaults
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

// schema defs

const roomSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

const gamerSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
})

const playerSchema = new Schema({
  gamer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Gamer' },
  kills: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  deaths: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  isAlive: { type: Boolean, default: true }
});

const matchSchema = new Schema({
  room: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Room' },
  team_one: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player' }],
  team_two: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player' }],
  finished: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

const Room = mongoose.model('Room', roomSchema);
const Gamer = mongoose.model('Gamer', gamerSchema);
const Player = mongoose.model('Player', playerSchema);
const Match = mongoose.model('Match', matchSchema);


// log helper
const log  = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));


// main
(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    // clean models
    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k, m]) => m.deleteMany())
    )

    // Insert to set up

    let room = await Room.create({ name: 'Room1' });

    let gamers = await Gamer.insertMany(
      [ ...Array(4)].map((e,i) => ({ name: 'Gamer' + (i+1) }))
    );

    let [player1, player2, player3, player4] = await Player.insertMany(
      gamers.map(({ _id: gamer }) => ({ gamer }))
    );

    let match = await Match.create({
      room,
      team_one: [player1, player2],
      team_two: [player3, player4],
    });

    // View match
    let storedMatch = await Match.findOne({ _id: match._id });
    log(storedMatch);

    // View populated
    let populated = await Match.findOne({ room: room._id })
      .populate('team_one')
      .populate('team_two');

    log(populated);


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect()
  }

})()
```

**Option 3**

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/matches';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

// sensible defaults
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

// schema defs

const roomSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

const gamerSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
})

const playerSchema = new Schema({
  gamer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Gamer' },
  kills: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  deaths: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  isAlive: { type: Boolean, default: true }
});

const matchSchema = new Schema({
  room: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Room' },
  players: [{
    team: { type: Number, required: true },
    player: playerSchema
  }],
  finished: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

const Room = mongoose.model('Room', roomSchema);
const Gamer = mongoose.model('Gamer', gamerSchema);
//const Player = mongoose.model('Player', playerSchema);
const Match = mongoose.model('Match', matchSchema);


// log helper
const log  = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));


// main
(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    // clean models
    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k, m]) => m.deleteMany())
    )

    // Insert to set up

    let room = await Room.create({ name: 'Room1' });

    let gamers = await Gamer.insertMany(
      [ ...Array(4)].map((e,i) => ({ name: 'Gamer' + (i+1) }))
    );

    let match = await Match.create({
      room,
      players: gamers.map((gamer,i) =>
        ({
          team: (i <= 1) ? 1 : 2,
          player: { gamer }
        })
      )
    });

    // View match
    let storedMatch = await Match.findOne({ _id: match._id });
    log(storedMatch);


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect()
  }

})()
```

**Option 4**

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/matches';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

// sensible defaults
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

// schema defs

const roomSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

const gamerSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
})

const playerSchema = new Schema({
  match: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Match' },
  team: { type: Number },
  gamer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Gamer' },
  kills: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  deaths: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  isAlive: { type: Boolean, default: true }
});

const matchSchema = new Schema({
  room: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Room' },
  finished: { type: Boolean, default: false }
},{
  toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});

matchSchema.virtual('players', {
  ref: 'Player',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'match'
});

const Room = mongoose.model('Room', roomSchema);
const Gamer = mongoose.model('Gamer', gamerSchema);
const Player = mongoose.model('Player', playerSchema);
const Match = mongoose.model('Match', matchSchema);


// log helper
const log  = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));


// main
(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    // clean models
    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k, m]) => m.deleteMany())
    )

    // Insert to set up

    let room = await Room.create({ name: 'Room1' });

    let gamers = await Gamer.insertMany(
      [ ...Array(4)].map((e,i) => ({ name: 'Gamer' + (i+1) }))
    );

    // Create match first
    let match = await Match.create({ room });


    // Add players with match reference
    let [player1, player2, player3, player4] = await Player.insertMany(
      gamers.map(({ _id: gamer }, i) =>
        ({ match, team: (i <= 1) ? 1 : 2, gamer })
      )
    );


    // View match
    let storedMatch = await Match.findOne({ _id: match._id });
    log(storedMatch);

    // View populated - virtual field
    let populated = await Match.findOne({ room: room._id })
      .populate('players')

    log(populated);


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect()
  }

})()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that material this will be very useful for me !!

Comment: Option 1: Population returns : { _id: [ObjectId] }...
Option 2: Works like a charm ! I choose that...
Option 3: Also works but it's a little bit complicated to iterate it on my view...
Option 4: Didn't try there is some concepts that I need to research (virtuals) but I will

Comment: @maudev For the record. they ALL work as expected with the specific code and examples for each case. I would normally even include the output within the answer, but there's a lot of content here and answers only get 30K characters to respond in. I believe the output listings go *just* over that. There to *demonstrate* how you use each form anyway.